# Trying to run a defined function with a delay

Tags: python, html, json, parsing, csv

I am trying to incrementally load values from the first column of a csv file into a URL and request the URL one at a time with a 5 second delay.  Each value in the first column should replace "theid"

This is my code so far:

```
 # I have a defined function
 def withid (theid):
    """"""


    global cache

    dupe = False

    theurl = "{0}{1}{2}".format(OMDBURL, "?i=", theid)

    response = urllib2.urlopen(theurl)

    movdata = json.load(response)

    for mov in cache:
        if movdata[MKEY[1]] == mov[MKEY[1]]:
            dupe = True
    if not dupe:
        cache.append(movdata)



outfile2 = open('outputrows2-shortened.csv', 'rb')
for row in outfile2:
  theid = outfile2(row[0])
  time.sleep(5)
```

output: TypeError: 'file' object is not callable

Comment: And... what is the problem?

Comment: It's not working, I'm just getting the error message above

Comment: That's because `withid` (now) returns a dict; you want to append it to jsonlist, not the other way around. Try `jsonlist.append(withid(row[0]))` instead.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm getting an HTTP error, meaning, I don't think the url is being populated with data from the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `withid()` function never returns anything. Try adding `return movdata` at the end of it.

Here is a rewritten version which may be helpful:

```
import csv
import json
import time
import urllib2

PAGE_DELAY = 5.    # time between loading pages
PAGE_LOAD  = 0.3   # how long it takes to load a page

make_url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt{}/'.format

def get_csv_column(csv_fname, col, **kwargs):
    with open(csv_fname, 'rb') as inf:
        incsv = csv.reader(inf, **kwargs)
        column = [row[col] for row in incsv]
    return column

def get_data_by_id(id):
    url = make_url(id)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data = json.load(response)
    return id,data

def delayed(delay, fn, *args):
    time.sleep(delay)
    return fn(*args)

def human_time(seconds):
    if seconds >= 86400:
        return '{:0.1f} days'.format(seconds / 86400.)
    elif seconds >= 3600:
        return '{:0.1f} hours'.format(seconds / 3600.)
    elif seconds >= 60:
        return '{:0.1f} minutes'.format(minutes / 60.)
    else:
        return '{:0.1f} seconds'.format(seconds)

def main():
    ids = get_csv_column('outputrows2.csv', 0)

    expected = (PAGE_DELAY + PAGE_LOAD) * len(ids)
    print('This will take about {}.'.format(human_time(expected)))

    results = (delayed(PAGE_DELAY, get_data_by_id, id) for id in ids)
    moviedata = dict(results)     # => gives dict of {id:data}

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: which one of these definitions can I output to a text file?

Comment: @kegewe: what do you want to put to the text file? `data` is a dictionary of whatever was returned as json; you need to pull whatever you are after from that and send it to your output file.

Comment: I want the entire JSON string for each ID in each line of the text file

Comment: @kegewe: then don't use `json.load(file)`, use `file.read()` and return that directly as a string.

Comment: problem is that I want to use that data in json format later, since `print moviedata` seemed to work, i was wondering if I could use the above edit I just made

Comment: I tried `with open('step3_desired_output.txt','w') as step3:
        step3.write(moviedata)` inside the main() function... but am getting an error: `TypeError: expected a character buffer object`

Comment: It also returns the json results in a strange order.  I'd like to try to get the results in the order that the JSON file delivers them in, without adding the id out in front of the response